# SDL2 not setting OpenGL version?

Tags: opengl, sdl2

I want to use SDL2 (2.0.4) with C to create an OpenGL 3.3 (core) context. But it seems to default to whatever compatibility profile my computer supports. Works fine with LWJGL2 and Java.

Here is my C code with SDL2.

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_events.h>
#include <epoxy/gl.h>
#include <epoxy/glx.h>

void main(){
    //set opengl attributes, supposed to happen before window creation
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute (SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE); //OpenGL core profile
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute (SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 3); //OpenGL 3+
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute (SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 3); //OpenGL 3.3

    if (SDL_Init (SDL_INIT_EVENTS | SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0){
        printf ("sdl init error: %s", SDL_GetError());
        return;
    }
    SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow (
        "SDL2 Problem",
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
        0,
        0,
        SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN_DESKTOP
    );
    if (window == NULL){
        printf ("could not create window: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        return;
    }

    //initialize OpenGL stuff
    SDL_GLContext openglContext = SDL_GL_CreateContext (window);
    printf ("glGetString (GL_VERSION) returns %s\n", glGetString (GL_VERSION));
    SDL_GL_DeleteContext (openglContext);
    SDL_DestroyWindow (window);
    SDL_Quit();
}
```

The output is

```
glGetString (GL_VERSION) returns 3.0 Mesa 11.2.0
```

So why is it not giving me an OpenGL 3.3 core profile? Here is my Java code with LWJGL2 (2.9.3)

```
import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.ContextAttribs;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.PixelFormat;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;

public class withLWJGL2{
    public static void main (String [] args){
        try{
            PixelFormat pixelFormat = new PixelFormat();
            ContextAttribs contextAttribs = new ContextAttribs (3, 3);//opengl 3.3
            Display.create (pixelFormat, contextAttribs);
        }
        catch (LWJGLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(0);
        }

        // check version string
        System.out.println ("glGetString (GL_VERSION) returns " + GL11.glGetString (GL11.GL_VERSION));

        Display.destroy();
    }
}
```

The output is

```
glGetString (GL_VERSION) returns 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 11.2.0
```

Works just fine! The output of

```
glxinfo | grep version
```

is

```
server glx version string: 1.4
client glx version string: 1.4
GLX version: 1.4
    Max core profile version: 3.3
    Max compat profile version: 3.0
    Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
    Max GLES[23] profile version: 3.0
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 11.2.0
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 11.2.0
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.0 Mesa 11.2.0
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.00
```

My computer is running GalliumOS 2.0, which is based on Ubuntu. Just to make sure it wasn't a problem with that computer I tried it on my other computer, running Ubuntu 16.04 and using NVIDIA. The ouput of the C code with SDL2 is

```
glGetString (GL_VERSION) returns 4.5.0 NVIDIA 361.42
```

So again it is not setting the version of the OpenGL context to OpenGL 3.3. The output of the Java code with LWJGL2 on this computer is

```
glGetString (GL_VERSION) returns 3.3.0 NVIDIA 361.42
```

Works just fine! Output of

```
glxinfo | grep version
```

is

```
server glx version string: 1.4
client glx version string: 1.4
GLX version: 1.4
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5.0 NVIDIA 361.42
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.50 NVIDIA
OpenGL version string: 4.5.0 NVIDIA 361.42
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.50 NVIDIA
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 NVIDIA 361.42
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
    GL_EXT_shader_implicit_conversions, GL_EXT_shader_integer_mix,
```

So in both cases the LWJGL2 works but the SDL2 seems to default to the highest compatibility profile that the drivers support. How can I get a 3.3 (core) profile with SDL2?

Comment: What if you set GL attributes after SDL init?

Comment: That was it! I'll post an answer.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat maybe post it as answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put your `SDL_GL_SetAttribute()` calls after `SDL_Init()`.